# Is there a source which states that the Baal Koreh should accompany the Sefer Torah back to the Ark?

Tags: torah-reading, sefer-torah, ark-aron-kodesh, hagbah-gelilah

[Shulchan Oruch  O Ch 23 149 (1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.149.1?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en) writes

> הגה - ובמקומות שמצניעין אותו בהיכל שהוא הארון בב"ה מצוה לכל מי שעוברת
>   לפניו ללותה עד לפני הארון שמכניסין אותו שם [ד"ע ומהרי"ל] וכן הגולל ילך
>   אחר הס"ת עד לפני הארון ועומד שם עד שיחזירו הס"ת למקומה [הג"מ פי"ב מה"ת
>   וכן נוהגין במגביה הס"ת כי הוא עיקר הגולל וכמו שנתבאר סי' קמ"ז ס"ד ויש
>   שכתבו שבאים התינוקות לנשק התורה כדי לחנכם ולזרזם במצות וכן  נוהגין
>   [אור זרוע]:‏
>
> Rema: All those who are passed by the Sefer Torah (on its journey back
>   to the Ark) should accompany it to just before the Ark. Similarly the
>   person who wrapped up the Sefer Torah and the one who lifted it up
>   should accompany the Sefer Torah to just before the Ark.

The Rema does not mention that the Reader, Baal Koreh, should  also accompany the Sefer Torah, but it seems obvious that he should.

Is there a source that specifically states that the Baal Koreh, should accompany the Sefer Torah back to in front of the Ark?

Comment: Never heard of such a thing - also never seen it; have you seen on Shabbat after אשרי all the Baalei Koreh coming up to the Bima to accompany the Sefer Torah?

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious to me. Why should he?The Baal Keriah is already back at his seat by then

Comment: I saw the Baal Koreh leaving the bimah in the opposite direction to the Sefer Torah on a Monday. That's where the question came up. But you are right. What was he doing there? He could have left by then.

Comment: Re last comment, "What was he doing there?" - as a *ba'al kri'ah* myself, I can tell you one reason - to reposition sifrei Torah for the next reading. (Even though Rosh Hodesh is on Thurs., I already have the Torot positioned from before.) Re your question, in general, keep in mind that originally, every *oleh* read his own *aliya*. Are you asking specifically about a dedicated *Ba'al kria*?  I'm inferring that if you split the parsha with 7 different people, you'd want a crowd up there. Only old shuls have a bimah that big!